# Send and retrieve key/value pair from MVC page to aspx page using POST Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have a MVC page with a hyperlink. The hyperlink redirects to an aspx page.
I want to send the data (key/value pair) from MVC page to aspx page when I redirect to aspx page. (MVC framework 5 and .Net framework 4.5)

And read the key/value pair in the Page_load of the aspx page.

I can't use query string or session or cookies.

How can I achieve this using HTTP-POST?

Comment: A hyperlink is a GET, not a POST

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#yourLinkId').on('click', function(){
       $.post("Controller/Method", { par1: "test", par2: "test2" } );
});
```

and with change page

```
$('a#yourLinkId').on('click', function(){
    $.post("Controller/Method", { par1: "test", par2: "test2" }, window.location.href = "Controller/Method");
});
```